# Button does not respond

Tags: java, android, button

Ive got a Button in one of my Fragments. But it seems to be "not-clickable". There is no Log.d. Message when I click the Button (In another Fragment (Same onclicklistenercode) everything is fine.
For greater overview I added the whole Class and the part of my layout file which defindes the button.

```js
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {

    DbHelper mydb;

    Button buttondeletedb;
    Button buttonexport;

    private EditText roomnr;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

        Context context = getContext();
        mydb = new DbHelper(context);

        buttondeletedb = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_deletelist_list);
        buttonexport = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_export);

        String dataList = mydb.getAllElements();                                                   
        String [] dataListArray = dataList.split("\n");                                             

        List<String> dataListFinal = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dataListArray));

        ArrayAdapter<String> dataListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(                                  
                getActivity(),                                                                      
                R.layout.list_item_datalist,                                                        
                R.id.list_item_datalist_textview,                                                   
                dataListFinal);                                                                     

        View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

        ListView dataListListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.datalist);
        dataListListView.setAdapter(dataListAdapter);


        buttondeletedb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("buttondeletelist", "clicked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                mydb.deleteAll();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


}
```

```js
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/deletelist"
                android:id="@+id/button_deletelist_list"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: is the button initialised

Comment: share code where you are filling the listview or where you initialise button

Comment: buttondeletedb = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_id); you have done it?

Comment: Problem might be with your XML. Eg. Parent of that button might be clickable.

Comment: Please post your full onCreateView() method code, also the xml file.

Comment: Sorry I deleted too much.

Comment: why u have taken two views in fragment with same xml file.

Comment: Copy and replace my answer. Your problem will solved.

Comment: Can you explain what you changed? Just copy and paste will solve the problem but I want to learn ;)

Comment: the problem is that u have taken two view with same xml file like View view and other is View rootview and u hv return rootview in fragment so it will take all the items which is find using rootview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Remove rootView and return view instead of rootView

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {

                DbHelper mydb;

                Button buttondeletedb;
                Button buttonexport;

                private EditText roomnr;

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listview, container, false);

                    Context context = getContext();
                    mydb = new DbHelper(context);

                    buttondeletedb = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_deletelist_list);
                    buttonexport = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_export);

                    String dataList = mydb.getAllElements();                                                   
                    String [] dataListArray = dataList.split("\n");                                             

                    List<String> dataListFinal = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(dataListArray));

                    ArrayAdapter<String> dataListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(                                  
                            getActivity(),                                                                      
                            R.layout.list_item_datalist,                                                        
                            R.id.list_item_datalist_textview,                                                   
                            dataListFinal);                                                                     
            // Change made here. replace view instead of rootView and remove rootView
                    ListView dataListListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.datalist);
                    dataListListView.setAdapter(dataListAdapter);


                    buttondeletedb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            Log.d("buttondeletelist", "clicked!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
                            mydb.deleteAll();
                        }
                    });
            // Replace rootView with view.
                    return view;
                }


            }
```

Comment: Its better to mention where you have made the changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can not click the button because the root view of Fragment is not **view**, you returned **rootView**. The button is child view of view.

Change `return rootView;` to `return view;`.

It should work

Answer (score 0):

Link between XML file and Class file of the Element (Button) is not there.Add this line in your onCreateView()

```
   Button buttondeletedb = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonid);
```